# Generate image for background in Batik

Tags: svg, batik

I have a method that generates an array of bytes, which can be represented as a two dimensional image. I would like to show this image as a background image in batik. I do not want to save the array to disk (as image) and then load it into batik. Instead I would like to provide the array to the batik. I though that using ParsedURLData can help me, but I can not figure out how to make it work. Any suggestions?

I call `ParsedURL.registerHandler(new MyProtocolHanlder("myprotocol"));` and `MyProtocolHanlder.parseURL` returns `MyParsedURLData`.

I thought that returning my own stream would work, but it does not. In the example bellow I simply load an image from disk and try to display it.

```
class MyParsedURLData extends ParsedURLData {
    public MyParsedURLData() {
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream openStreamRaw(String arg0, Iterator arg1) throws IOException {
        return new File("some_image_here").toURI().toURL().openStream();
    }

}
```

If in the constructor for `MyParsedURLData` I set `protocol = "file"` and `path="another_image"`, then another image will be loaded, no matter what stream is returned by `openStreamRaw`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to save the image to a temp file, then just reference it via `File.toURI().toURL()`, and Batik will load it. You don't need a custom protocol handler or `ParsedURL` for this. Choose a standard image format supported by Batik such as `PNG` or `JPEG` for the temp file!

You can save the temp file by implementing both a `ParsedURLProtocolHandler` and a `RegistryEntry` and register them with Batik. There is a little bit of documentation on that on the web site, but it is still a pain to do. Took me some hours to figure out (and the code is not really ready for sharing), but I can now pass a `BufferedImage` directly to Batik without encoding it as a `.png` or similar file first.